# compare the two lines

Tags: sql

There are two columns, in the same table.
I need to find values that are in the second column but not in the first.
All I've been able to think of so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [column],
FROM [table]
WHERE column2 LIKE "2";
```

I know the task is simple, but do you have any ideas?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your code snippet seems to have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: select * from table where column2 == "2" and column1 != "2";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to find values that are in the second column but not in the first.

This suggests `not exists` or a similar approach:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.column2 = t.column1);
```